# How to setup Mongo DB & PHP with core Mac OS 10.6.8, default Apache instance/Web Sharing

Tags: php, mongodb, pear

I am attempting to configure PHP and Mongo DB to connect with one another and I'm having some troubles. Before I say the problem let me recap what I have so far.

I am using MAC OS X 10.6.8

I have mongo DB installed and working stand-alone.

I have enabled PHP on the default Mac OS Apache web server. It is working and the server recognizes PHP ( it is not allowing inline PHP scripts in HTML files...*not sure if this an issue*)

"Web sharing" works just fine.

I have installed pear via this url:     curl -O http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar

I have the pear folder and files accessible and have launched **o-pear.php** from a web browser.

I have gone through the step-by-step install process ( and removed any red displayed errors ).

Presumably Pear is now installed.

It says at the bottom of the install front end:

> Note: To use PEAR without any problems you need to add your PEAR
>   Installation path (/Users/myname/Sites/PEAR) to your
>   include_path.
>
> Using a .htaccess file or directly edit httpd.conf would be working
>   solutions for Apache running servers, too.

I am not sure what the code is I need to add  for the httaccess rewrite.

As of this moment
Terminal does not recognize the **pear** command.
When I launch the pear "front end" from a web browser I get:

```
Fatal error: No PEAR.php in supplied PEAR directory: /Users/myname/Sites/PEAR in /Users/myname/Sites/index.php on line 24
```

Thank you.
That is all.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new PHP file called `phpinfo.php`. Add the content `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` there. Run the script from within your webbrowser.

You should see a big page with PHP configuration information. Watch out for `include_path`. This is where your webserver/PHP module/process searches for include files.

You will also find `Loaded Configuration File`. This is the PHP configuration file being used. Open that file in any editor, and search for `include_path` again. Add `/Users/myname/Sites/PEAR` to the end of the `include_path`.

Restart your webserver. PEAR now should work.

If you need to install the MongoDB PHP extension, go for `pecl install mongo` from command line.

Comment: The include path is: .:/usr/lib/php                             The Loaded  Configuration File directory is (none). Not sure what to do. Should I manually create this file?